# How to stop counting blank page XSLT/XSLFO

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

I have a layout which starts at page number 1 and continues. Now the problem is it counts the blank pages as well. Is there any way to force stop blank page counting.

**Current output** :

Page 1(not-blank) - page number 1 of 6

Page 2(blank)

Page 3(not-blank) - page number 3 of 6

Page 4(blank)

Page 5(not-blank) - page number 5 of 6

Page 6(blank)

**Expected output:**

Page 1(not-blank) - page number 1 of 3

Page 2(blank)

Page 3(not-blank) - page number 2 of 3

Page 4(blank)

Page 5(not-blank) - page number 3 of 3

Page 6(blank)

Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" >
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master margin-left="0.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.5in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" master-name="PageFront">
                <fo:region-body region-name="letterPageBody" margin-left="0pt" margin-top="3.5in" margin-right="0pt" margin-bottom="1in" />
                <fo:region-before extent="4in" region-name="FirstPageHeader" precedence="true" />
                <fo:region-after extent="0.8in" region-name="letterPageFooter" precedence="true" background-color="yellow" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:simple-page-master margin-left="0.5in" margin-top="0.5in" margin-right="0.5in" margin-bottom="0.5in" page-height="11in" page-width="8.5in" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" master-name="Blank">
                <fo:region-body margin-left="0pt" margin-top="3.5in" margin-right="0pt" margin-bottom="1in" region-name="letterPageBody2" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="LetterPages">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageFront" page-position="first" odd-or-even="odd" />
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="Blank" odd-or-even="even" />
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageFront" odd-or-even="odd" />
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence force-page-count="auto" initial-page-number="auto" master-reference="LetterPages">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="letterPageFooter">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='Footer']" />
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="FirstPageHeader">
                <fo:table width="100%" table-layout="fixed">
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block background-color="#67D217">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='address']" />
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="center">Page <fo:page-number /> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="LastPage" /></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                </fo:table>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="letterPageBody">
                <fo:block background-color="#F1F1F1">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="//region[@name='Body']" />
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block id="LastPage" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>

 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output of the above is(assuming there's two pages to display)

First Page (non-blank) Page 1 of 3

Second Page (blank)

Third Page (non-blank) Page 3 of 3

> edit

This is the document which uses the above xsl(This is a custom tool written based on Apache-FOP)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<docdef version="5.1"  numbering-format="1">
<scriptlinks />
<script language="JavaScript" />
<interview-data />
<template-edition channel="2" template="">
    <edition-content>
        <sectionmap section="Body" region="Body" />
        <sectionmap section="Footer" region="Footer" />
        <sectionmap section="Header" region="address" />
    </edition-content>
</template-edition>
<section id="" name="Document">
    <section id="" name="Body">
        <frag id="" name="new text fragment" no-match="error" type="text">
            <edition id="" name="new text fragment" withdrawn="False">
                <edition-content>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">hen it is 5°F outside?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Wearing a cape during combat?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">What's between the finite and the infinite?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">What was C-3PO talking about when he said, “That’s funny, the damage doesn’t look as bad from out here.”</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Intersperse lines from two files</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">How to find an employer who is NOT child friendly?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Why does Binary exist?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">How many layers are too many layers in ArcMap?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Quinean Regex Tester</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Is it safe to post one's research on web sites like Math Overflow for "peer review" before submitting to a journal?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Does a mourner tear one garment, or every garment he wears for a period of time?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Particle between city and prefecture?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Surrounded Countries</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Why would security cover things like natural disasters?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">How do exit interviews benefit the company?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Mystery 1970's Sci Fi Novel titled "Planet of the Gworfs" (or perhaps planet of the "Gwarfs")</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Getting a US minor passport when you can't find one parent</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Open source software capable of open Sketch files</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Is it possible to spread holy water on a weapon like you do with poison?</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">more hot questions</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">question feed</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">tour help blog chat data legal privacy policy work here advertising info mobile contact us feedback</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">TECHNOLOGY    LIFE / ARTS    CULTURE / RECREATION    SCIENCE    OTHER</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Stack Overflow</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Server Fault</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Super User</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Web Applications</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Ask Ubuntu</p>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Webmasters</p>
                </edition-content>
            </edition>
        </frag>
    </section>
    <section id="" name="Header">
        <frag id="" name="new text fragment" no-match="error" type="text">
            <edition id="" name="new text fragment" withdrawn="False">
                <edition-content>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Page <page-numbering value="current.page" /> of <page-numbering value="total.pages" /></p>
                </edition-content>
            </edition>
        </frag>
    </section>
    <section id="" name="Footer">
        <frag id="" name="new text fragment" no-match="error" type="text">
            <edition id="" name="new text fragment" withdrawn="False">
                <edition-content>
                    <p xml:space="preserve">Type your text here...</p>
                </edition-content>
            </edition>
        </frag>
    </section>
</section>
```

In the above

```
<template-edition channel="2" template="">
<edition-content>
    <sectionmap section="Body" region="Body" />
    <sectionmap section="Footer" region="Footer" />
    <sectionmap section="Header" region="address" />
</edition-content>
```

Example : 
'Header' is mapped to XSL region 'address' (same for others)

Comment: Please also show the XML input (the document that contains `region` elements). Thanks.

Comment: There are still no `region` elements in your input, and if regions are actually `sections`, there is no `region[@name='address']` in the document. There is a reference to an inexistent `letterPageBody2`. If I correct all this and add more text, the second page does not come out as blank.

Comment: <sectionmap section="Header" region="address" /> This line indicates the mapping

Answer (score 2):

*If* all your pages come from a single `fo:page-sequence`, there is no *direct* way to achieve your desired output.

In the [XSL recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_simple-page-master) the value of `fo:page-number` is defined as the **folio-number** trait of a page, which is computed according to these rules:

> 1. The value of the folio-number trait on the first page returned by the `fo:page-sequence` is constrained to equal the value of the `initial-page-number` trait.
> 2. The value of the folio-number trait on subsequent pages is constrained to be one greater than the value on the immediately preceding page.

In other words, you can decide the initial number for the first page deriving from a `page-sequence`, but **consecutive pages get consecutive page numbers** (regardless of their being shown in the page or not).

That is the general answer; in your specific situation there could be *indirect* ways to get what you want:

- it could be possible to separate your content into different `page-sequence`s so that each one produces a full page and a blank one (setting `force-page-count="even"` and using `initial-page-number="2"` on the second `page-sequence`, and so on ...)
- with a two steps approach, you could use FOP's [intermediate format feature](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/intermediate.html) to

  1. create the outpt with no blank pages, with the desired page numbers
  2. insert blank pages between the numbered ones

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active in the recent years)*